# Inserting Pictures for examples in questions

Tags: support

I can't find in 'Help' where it instructs us how to insert pictures to help with questions

Comment: There is a help icon *in the editor you used to create this post*. It includes help on images. There is a link in the help menu that appears too, it leads to https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images

Comment: In addition, when I search the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for the term *images*, I find three pages including https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting, which has a section on formatting images in posts.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Comment: i really aught to -1 for not using [a free hand circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/250962)